# How can I debug a native code DLL written in VC++.NET 2010 Express called from an exe written in VB.NET 2010 Express?

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++, dll, express, visual-studio-debugging

According to Microsoft you cannot do this by starting in the DLL using the 2010 Express version of vc++.net but you **can** (they say) put a break in the VC++.NET DLL then start your exe in VB.NET and then step into it. (Using F8 presumably—being Microsoft they would not deign to actually say "using F8".)

When I try it, it doesn't go into the DLL when I press F8 (nor if I right click on the F9 breakpoint in VB.NET exe and use "Step into Specific" etc). It uses the DLL fine and returns the correct result but I cannot get inside the DLL.

I am using 2010 Express because I am on Win XP and cannot use 2013 on XP. I use Win XP because I still need VB6 and it will not install the VB6 IDE on Win 7/8.

Comment: Unfortunately the editing process destroyed the key part of the question. The point is that BOTH the DLL and the VB.net part are written in the 2010 Express Versions. Had they been written in the paid for versions then debugging is probably easy to do. So, how do I do this given the above? Regarding the editing process, this is my first question and I got a message saying suggested edits. Obviously, I assumed that I could responf somehow but evidently not. So, you should put this as "these are edits, this is how the question will be posed and tough luck if you don't like our edits"

Comment: You have to explicitly enable the unmanaged code debugging engine to get breakpoints to work in native code.  Projects + Properties, Debug tab, "Enable native code debugging" checkbox.  Not actually sure if that's available in Express.  Paying attention to the breakpoint indicator is important, if it looks hollowed out instead of a solid red dot then the breakpoint wasn't armed and can't cause a break.

Comment: There is no such checkbox in 2010 Express. I have done a search on "Enable native code debugging" and find the following answer regarding this absence:

"This is by design - mixed-mode debugging (debug both managed and native code) is not supported on VS 2010, it requires 2012+. There isn't anything we can do about this, unfortunately, since mixed-mode requires the new cooperative native debugging engine that debuted in VS 2012"

So, that looks like the end of the line ... so now I must change to 2013 probably which adds a whole lot more problems